# ¿Por qué no funciona mi código de VBA?

Tags: excel, lista, vb.net, windows-forms, vba

Lo que intento hacer es que excel copie una columna a la derecha del valor que le indico encontrar. Debe buscar en varios archivos que tienen estructura similar. Sin embargo cuando lo hace con el segundo archivo sobrescribe el valor de la segunda columna en la misma fila del nuevo archivo. Les dejo el código que tengo hasta ahora.
Valoraría mucho su ayuda.
Gracias.

```
Sub TransposeAndCopyMultipleFiles()
    Dim fileNames As Variant
    Dim fileName As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim destWb As Workbook
    Dim destWs As Worksheet
    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim foundCell As Range

    
    fileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsArray(fileNames) = False Then Exit Sub ' El usuario canceló la selección

    
    Set destWb = Application.Workbooks.Add
    Set destWs = destWb.Sheets(1)

    
    For Each fileName In fileNames
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName)

        
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        Set foundCell = ws.Range("1:3").Find("BOM Accuracy")

        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = ws.Range(foundCell.Offset(0, 1), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Column).End(xlUp))
            rng.Copy
            nextRow = destWs.Cells(destWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If nextRow < 2 Then nextRow = 2 
            destWs.Cells(nextRow, "B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

            
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If

       
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next fileName

    
    destWb.SaveAs "\Results.xlsx" 

End Sub
```

Comment: No queda claro qué debe ocurrir si encuentra el valor a buscar en más de un fichero. ¿Deben copiarse las columnas de forma consecutiva?. Deberias poner un ejemplo de lo que tienes y lo que esperas conseguir.
En tú código (destWs.Cells(nextRow, "B").PasteSpecial) indicas que siempre deben pegarse los datos en la columna B. Por eso te machaca siempre los datos anteriores. Deberías tener algo que controle cual ha sido la última columna destino.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en el valor que obtienes en `nextRow`, la base para eso es la columna **A**, pero los datos se escriben en la columna **B**, entonces, cuando llegas al segundo archivo, como en la columna **A** no se escribió nada, devolverá el mismo numero de fila que en la iteración anterior, por lo tanto al escribir en la columna **B**, lo hace en la misma fila, sobrescribiendo su valor.

Básicamente tienes que cambiar esto:

```
nextRow = destWs.Cells(destWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Por esto:

```
nextRow = destWs.Cells(destWs.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```